# MS SQL Server - Script vs Project vs Solution

Tags: sql-server

Can someone define these 3 terms for me? I think my understanding of them is very over simplified right now. This is what I am thinking

scripts (.sql) - bunch of queries put together on one page. This is what is created when you go to Project>New Query.

projects (.ssmssqlpro) - this just gathers all your scripts in one spot. Instead of opening each script one by one, you can open the project and it'll load all the scripts at once.

solutions (.ssmssln) - this one I have no clue what it does. If i would guess, I'd say it combines a multiple projects together.

So when I open a Solution or Project, it looks to be the same. When I open a script it only opens a single script, which makes sense to me. I know I am very wrong with a lot of my definitions, please help explain to me these 3 terms and in what situations I would use them in.

(The reason I am asking is I am wondering which ones I should use for my assignment. I need to write a lot of queries that uses data from database1 and creates new tables in database2, with database1 and database2 being part of the same connection.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a full discussion [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/solution/solutions-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017)

> Projects can contain:
>
> Queries and scripts that implement production processes.
>
> Connection information and files used by the queries and scripts.
>
> One or more related projects can be combined in a solution. Solutions
>   and projects can be managed by using the Solution Explorer pane in
>   Management Studio.

Comment: Can you create a project without a solution?

Comment: And is creating Projects and Scripts mainly for organization purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct:

- Script files (.sql) contain one or more queries (or any other T-SQL batch)
- Projects (.ssmssqlproj) contain multiple scripts and multiple connections
- Solutions (.ssmssln) contain one or more projects.

You can create a project without a solution, but SSMS will always steer you into creating a solution.  This is why it looks the same to you when you open a project or a solution.

It sounds like your assignment would be best as a ssms project, as you have many scripts to group together.

It is worth noting that there is [another type of sql project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-create-a-new-database-project?view=sql-server-ver16) that has far more features and benefits.  That type of sql project (.sqlproj) is opened using Visual Studio with the [SSDT add-on](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/) installed and it allows you to create the definitions of an entire database, including stored procedures.  One of the main benefits of that type of project is that you can save the project in source control such as git, TFS, etc.